# Blacklisting tld in postfix

Tags: postfix

In my postfix setup I want to "disable" all incoming mail from a specific TLD domain (in my case, all domains ending with ".info"). My usual way to block domains is using a hashed file in `/etc/postfix/rejected_domains`, that looks like this

```
[...]
bla.info     REJECT Spam
blubb.info   REJECT More Spam!
[...]
```

and having this piece of configuration in my `main.cf` file:

```
# domains to be restricted
smtpd_sender_restrictions = hash:/etc/postfix/rejected_domains
reject_unauth_destinations = hash:/etc/postfix/rejected_domains
```

My idea to block all of info was adding these rules into the above file:

```
*.info  REJECT Toooo much spam
.info   REJECT Toooo much spam
```

Unluckily this does not seem to work.

Using postfix `2.8.5-2~build0.10.04` on Ubuntu LTS 10 here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hash is for literals (exact matches), you want to use regex or pcre:

as [Overmind](https://serverfault.com/users/267184/overmind) pointed out, you want to append these if you already have values, you can check you existing values with

```
postconf smtpd_sender_restrictions
postconf reject_unauth_destinations
```

Then you can override them with:

```
postconf -e smtpd_sender_restrictions=pcre:/etc/postfix/rejected_domains
postconf -e reject_unauth_destinations=pcre:/etc/postfix/rejected_domains
```

contents of /etc/postfix/rejected_domains:

```
/\.info$/           REJECT All Info Domains
```

and then `postfix reload`

Comment: Thanks for your input, is there no need to `postmap` the referenced file?

Comment: Correct, postmap is for hash or lmdb files

Comment: Note that this will replace other restriction settings. It's best to edit the file directly.

Comment: can also catch tld's at helo restrictions if they present a tld.. and as needed..

Comment: Also note: depending on the distribution of postfix, it may or may not have pcre dictionary support. Just install it. (In my case I installed `sudo apt install postfix-pcre`)

Comment: Another thing may may find quite useful: if you want exceptions to a TLD block, you can do it under the format /exception\.info$/ . The "\" there is used to make the dot a dot and not an 'all' character.

Answer (score 0):

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_blacklist
    check_helo_access hash:/etc/postfix/helo_whitelist
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname
```

In helo_blacklist

```
info REJECT INFO tld blocked
```

execute `postmap helo_blacklist`

Servers presenting a helo ending in info will get an error like:

```
Helo command rejected: INFO tld blocked;
```

Comment: I've thought the `smtpd_helo_restrictions` is a comma separated list, but the documentation says your syntax is valid, too: "Specify a list of restrictions, separated by commas and/or whitespace." On the other hand, the question wasn't about HELO hostnames.

Comment: The question is about "Blacklisting tld in postfix", which my solution actually does.

Comment: Not really, because the HELO hostname is not required to match the envelope sender.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in the accepted answer, the [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) does not take the `pcre:` directly, but requires `check_sender_access type:table`.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access
```

Then, the `/etc/postfix/sender_access` can have:

```
/\.info$/  550  I do not accept mail from .info
/\.icu$/   550  https://blocked.icu/
```

Comment: And a test like the following for the example above:
`postmap -fq "FROM: serverfault.info" pcre:/etc/postfix/sender_access`
with a result like:  `550  I do not accept mail from .info`